# ArrayAdapter in relative layout - Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to re-familiarize myself with Android by implementing the examples given on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com).

I am trying [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example) on RelativeLayouts. While the layout is clear to me, I am not able to add functionality to the spinners given there. Here is what I am trying to do:
Give the user the option of choosing a date from any one of the next 7 days to set an alarm. For this, I want to populate the spinner with an `ArrayAdapter` that is set dynamically every time the application is started. The content of the `ArrayAdapter` would be the current date and the next 7 days. I am unable to initialize the `ArrayAdapter`.
Given that the content is dynamic, is `ArrayAdapter` the best data structure to use?

The code:

```
activity_main.xml:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/reminderName"
        android:hint="@string/reminderNameString"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/dateSelect"
        android:layout_below="@id/reminderName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeSelect"
        android:hint="@string/selectDate"
        />

    <Spinner android:id="@id/timeSelect"
        android:hint="@string/selectTimeString"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/reminderName"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/setButton"
        android:hint="@string/setString"
        android:layout_below="@id/timeSelect"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/reminderName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onSet"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The main function:

```
package com.example.relativelayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner dates;
    Spinner times;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* This function must move like so:
         * 1. Generate the dates.
         * 2. Add them to an arrayList
         * 3. Set the data via an adapter into the spinner.
         * 4. Set the layout.
         */

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Loaded the layout");

        //init ArrayList object to store all the dates.
        ArrayList<String> dates_list = new ArrayList<String>(8);  //there are always only 7 days.

        Date d = new Date();  //initialize the date to current date and time.
        dates_list.add(d.toString());
        //GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
        Log.v(this.toString(), "Current date = " + d.toString());

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if( (d.getMonth() % 2 != 0) || (d.getMonth() == 8) ) {
                //the month has 31 days.
                int dateAdj = d.getDate();
                if( (dateAdj + i) > 31 ) {
                    dateAdj = (dateAdj + i) - 31;
                    d.setDate(dateAdj);
                    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
                } else {
                    d.setDate((dateAdj + 1));
                }
            } else {  //the month has only 30 days
                int dateAdj = d.getDate();
                if( (dateAdj + i) > 30 ) {
                    dateAdj = (dateAdj + i) - 30;
                    d.setDate(dateAdj);
                    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
                } else {
                    d.setDate((dateAdj + 1));
                }
            }           
            dates_list.add(d.toString());  //add it to the list.
            //Log.v(this.toString(), "The date today = " + d.toString());
        }

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Printing details of the arrayList");

        /*for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Date in position " + i + " " + dates_list.get(i));
        }*/

        //have all the dates in the prescribed format. add it to the spinners.
        ArrayAdapter<String> array_adapter_dates = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dates_list);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Adding dates to array adapters.");

        //init the spinner from the layouts.
        dates = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dateSelect);  //got the spinner
        array_adapter_dates.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Spinners initialized. Moving to apply adapters to the spinner.");

        //apply adapter to the spinner.
        dates.setAdapter(array_adapter_dates);

        Log.v(this.toString(), "Applied adapter to the spinner.");

        //set the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSet(View view) {
        /*This is the function called when the Set button is pressed.
         *  1. Take the details of the spinners.
         *  2. Flash them.
         *  3. Set an alarm with it.
         */

        Log.v(this.toString(), "onSet() function inboked.");        
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an Arraylist then add the date.tostring to this arraylist rather than adding Date object to the adapter.

Using this ArrayList create an ArrayAdapter

```
array_adapter_dates = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Arraylist<String>)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Initializing the arrayList did help. After initializing the arrayAdapter, I am unable to populate the spinner with its contents. I have edited the main class appropriately. More help is needed!

Comment: move the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); immediately after super.oncreate, otherwise findviewbyid doesnt work